# JQuery : TickInterval in JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

How can I set the tickInterval in x-axis for a jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ? The x-axis labels are strings.

I try the code below, but it does not work. Help please, thanks.

```
xaxis: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
         tickOptions: {
             angle: -90,
             fontSize: '12pt'
         },
         tickInterval : 10,
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
         ticks: ticks,
         label: '<%= chartBy.replace("_", " ").toUpperCase()%>',
         labelOptions:{
              enableFontSupport:true,
              fontFamily:'Verdana',
              fontSize: '12pt'
         }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The property `tickInterval` is a string field. Try setting it like this:

```
xaxis:{
//Other options
tickInterval: '1 day',
//Another options
}
```

I've searched another options and these are the ones i've tested (they work):

- `'1 day'`
- `'x days'` where x is any integer greater than 1
- `'1 week'`
- `'x weeks'` where x is any integer greater than 1
- `'1 month'`
- `'x months'` where x is any integer greater than 1

Note that these are case-sensitive options. So, `'month'` is different than `'Month'`.